# how to add select option to datagrid control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="Server" id="dg"></asp:DataGrid>
```

Comment: And the **question** for this line of markup is.......

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a number of ways, but the most configurable is likely going to be by adding a [TemplateColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479316.aspx) and putting the controls you need in that column.

Answer (score 0):

look this

```
 <asp:DataGrid  runat="server">
   <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateColumn>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList  runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
         </ItemTemplate> 
      </asp:TemplateColumn>
   </Columns>
 </asp:DataGrid>
```